# Is there a cocos2d solution for creating a parent container

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, containers

Is there a cocos2d solution for creating a parent container (CCNode or CCSprite) which its childrens are not visible beyond parent container bounds.

Think as a container node as X ands its childrens Y and Z,
Y and Z must be partially and then totally invisible while dragging outside of X' bounds,

I know it is possible with TextureRect but , is there any ready using cocos2d component or any easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can use a `CCClippingNode`.

You can find out how to use it in the documentation: 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCClippingNode.html